# Understanding Ballot contract calling in web3

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, solidity

Contract:

```
contract Ballot {

    struct Voter {
        uint weight; //weight is accumulated by delegation
        bool voted; //if true, that person already voted
        address delegate; //person delegated to
        uint vote; //index of the voted proposal
    }

    struct Proposal {
        bytes32 name;    // short name (up to 32 bytes)
        uint voteCount; //number of accumulated votes
    }

    address public chairperson;

    // This declares a state variable that
    // stores a `Voter` struct for each possible address.
    mapping(address => Voter) public voters;

    Proposal[] public proposals;

    /// Create a new ballot to choose one of `proposalNames`.
    constructor(bytes32[] proposalNames) public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 1;

        // For each of the provided proposal names,
        // create a new proposal object and add it
        // to the end of the array.
        for (uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
            proposals.push(Proposal({
                    name: proposalNames[i],
                        voteCount: 0
                }));
        }
    }

    // Give `voter` the right to vote on this ballot.
    // May only be called by `chairperson`.
    function giveRightToVote(address voter) public {
        // If the first argument of `require` evaluates
        // to `false`, execution terminates and all
        // changes to the state and to Ether balances are reverted.
        // This used to consume all gas in old EVM versions, but not anymore.
        // It is often a good idea to use `require` to check if functions are called correctly.
        // As a second argument, you can also provide an explanation about what went wrong.
        require(msg.sender == chairperson, "Only chairperson can give right to vote.");
        require(!voters[voter].voted, "The voter already voted.");
        require(voters[voter].weight == 0);
        voters[voter].weight = 1;
    }

    /// Delegate your vote to the voter `to`.
    function delegate(address to) public {
        // assigns reference
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(!sender.voted, "You already voted.");

        require(to != msg.sender, "Self-delegation is disallowed.");
        while (voters[to].delegate != address(0)) {
            to = voters[to].delegate;

                // We found a loop in the delegation, not allowed.
            require(to != msg.sender, "Found loop in delegation.");
        }

        // Since `sender` is a reference, this
        // modifies `voters[msg.sender].voted`
            sender.voted = true;
            sender.delegate = to;
            Voter storage delegate_ = voters[to];
            if (delegate_.voted) {
                // If the delegate already voted,
                // directly add to the number of votes
               proposals[delegate_.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
            } else {
                // If the delegate did not vote yet,
                // add to her weight.
                delegate_.weight += sender.weight;
            }
        }

    /// Give your vote (including votes delegated to you)
    /// to proposal `proposals[proposal].name`.
    function vote(uint proposal) public {
            Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
            require(!sender.voted, "Already voted.");
            sender.voted = true;
            sender.vote = proposal;

            // If `proposal` is out of the range of the array,
            // this will throw automatically and revert all changes.
            proposals[proposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }

    function winningProposal() public view returns (uint winningProposal_) {
            uint winningVoteCount = 0;
            for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
                if (proposals[p].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                        winningVoteCount = proposals[p].voteCount;
                        winningProposal_ = p;
                    }
            }
    }

    // Calls winningProposal() function to get the index
    // of the winner contained in the proposals array and then
    // returns the name of the winner
    function winnerName() public view returns (bytes32 winnerName_) {
            winnerName_ = proposals[winningProposal()].name;
    }

    function getCount(uint p) public view returns (uint count_) {
            count_ = proposals[p].voteCount;
    }
}
```

javascript:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
        var balance = web3.eth.getBalance(coinbase);
        var abi = JSON.parse('[{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"proposal\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"vote\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"proposals\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"bytes32\"},{\"name\":\"voteCount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"chairperson\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"delegate\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"winningProposal\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"winningProposal_\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"voter\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"giveRightToVote\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"voters\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"weight\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"voted\",\"type\":\"bool\"},{\"name\":\"delegate\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"vote\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"p\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"getCount\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"count_\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"winnerName\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"winnerName_\",\"type\":\"bytes32\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"proposalNames\",\"type\":\"bytes32[]\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"constructor\"}]');
        var cont = web3.eth.contract(abi).at("0x68497A36A8E322EA25d3d6CD6E15BcF5855AC560");
        sign();
        cont.giveRightToVote.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[0], {from:coinbase, gas:250000}, function(err, transactionHash){   
            if(!err){
                console.log(transactionHash);
            }
            else{ alert(err); }
        });

        // cont.giveRightToVote.call(web3.eth.accounts[1], function(err, res){
        //     console.log(res);   
        // });

        function give_vote(){ 
            cont.delegate.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[2], {from:coinbase, gas:250000}, function (err, trans){
                cont.vote.sendTransaction(2, {from:coinbase, gas:250000}, function(err,   transactionHash){   
                if(!err){
                    console.log(transactionHash);
                }
                else{ alert(err); }
                });
            });

        }
        function view(){
            cont.winnerName.call(function(err, result){
                console.log(result);  
            });
            cont.getCount.call(0, function(err, res){
                console.log(res);  
            });
        }
```

eth.accounts[0] voting is accepted. when try to do eth.accounts[1 or 2] it is not counting vote. how can make other account also participate in the voting system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have set defined your initial/primary account as the coinbase:

```
miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])
```

So `eth.accounts[0]` is `chairperson` who has the right to vote as defined in the constructor.

`chairperson` will give the right to vote for `eth.accounts[1]` and `eth.accounts[2]`

You need to call a function to give the right to vote for accounts 1 and 2.

```
cont.giveRightToVote.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[1], {from:coinbase, gas:250000}, function(err, transactionHash){   
    if(!err){
        console.log(transactionHash);
    }
    else{ alert(err); }
})
 cont.giveRightToVote.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[2], {from:coinbase, gas:250000}, function(err, transactionHash){   
        if(!err){
            console.log(transactionHash);
        }
        else{ alert(err); }
    })
```

delegate function is delegating right to vote of coinbase(accounts[0]) to accounts[2]. Now accounts[0] will vote on behalf of account[2]. account[2] cannot participate in the voting as he has delegated his voting right to account[0].

Comment: What is delegate function?             is this correct ?cont.delegate.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[2], {from:coinbase, gas:250000}, function (err, trans){

Comment: delegate function is delegating right to vote of coinbase(accounts[0]) to accounts[2]. Now accounts[0] will vote on behalf of account[2].  account[2] cannot participate in the voting as he has delegated his voting right to account[0].

Comment: i understood your explanation. contract is not working as expected. i tried same in remix also but is not working. i have eth.accounts[0] to accounts[6]. i have deployed contract with 0, 1, 2, 3 proposals.  eth.acccounts[1] voted for 2nd proposal. winningPropsal is 2. then eth.accout[2]. eth.account[3], eth.account[4] voted for 3rd proposal. Afterthat i checked winning propsal. still giving output 2nd proposal. it supposed to be 3rd proposal. would you please share your contact mail to chat?

Comment: thanks dude. it is working fine. i have some other doubts. how to get resposnse or how to identify the response incase of  address already voted, voting rights is not yet given for this address?. i am getting only transaction hash, even voted or already voted.

Comment: Welcome! I am glad to help you. To get smart contract return values for the user interface you need to use solidity events. Read the following tutorial for more details - https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e